# xxx is not a valid virtual path?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xmldatasource, virtual-path

I use `XmlDataSource` like this  :

```
<asp:XmlDataSource ID="xmlDataSource1" runat="Server" DataFile="https://myurl.xml" ></asp:XmlDataSource>
```

as a datasource to my `rotater` control.

---

but i get the following exception all the time :

> https://myurl.xml is not a valid virtual path.

Although i tried the link externally and there's an xml file

Comment: In fact, `XmlDataSource` works fine with `http` urls but it did not work with `https` URL -- got the exact same error you mentioned.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ignore my previous answer. Apparently the `XmlDataSource` does not like https URLs as the `DataFile`:

```
// works
xmlDataSource1.DataFile = "http://code.google.com/feeds/p/google-code-prettify/svnchanges/basic";
// does not work
xmlDataSource1.DataFile = "https://code.google.com/feeds/p/google-code-prettify/svnchanges/basic";
```

Write a few extra lines of code to download the XML from https source like:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://code.google.com/feeds/p/google-code-prettify/svnchanges/basic");
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()); 
string str = reader.ReadToEnd();
// save it or set it as the .Data property of XmlDataSource
```

Comment: then if i have an `xml` file from `url` like what i have .What should i do . copy it firstly to a local folder in my server or what ?

Comment: yes, I would give that a try! download the remote file and save it in a location accessible by asp.net

Comment: hmmm,there 's no way except that?, why i can't consider this as alive datasource instead of copy the file in my server?